# how to access variables in symfony controller?

Tags: php, symfony

I wanted to use a class variable in symphony controller but it does not work. I want to set it runtime by post method and then retrieve it another function of same controller. I tried with session it works but I dont want to use session.

```
class TestController extends Controller{
private $test;

public function someAction(){
$testVal = $this->getTest(); 
print_r($testVal); // its null
}

public function someAnotherAction(){
$this->setTest($_POST["test"]);
}

public function setTest($value){
$this->test= $value;
}

public function getTest(){
return $this->test;
}
}
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to do? You can't set a variable that will still be set when you call another route. Each time you call a route/action, the controller is instantiated, and the test property is reset. There probably is a better way to achieve what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

You don't call `$_POST["test"]` inside the class.
Instead use `setTest($value)` when calling the class

```
$myclass->setTest($_POST["test"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony controller you can use Symfony requests:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class TestController extends Controller{
    private $test;

    public function someAction(){
        $testVal = $this->getTest(); 
        print_r($testVal); // its null
    }

    public function someAnotherAction(Request $request){
        $this->setTest($request->query->get('test'));
    }

    public function setTest($value){
        $this->test= $value;
   }

    public function getTest(){
        return $this->test;
   }
}
```